# Поведение e.target и клик

Tags: javascript, события

Есть такой код

```js
$(document).on('click', function(e){
    if(e.target !== '.profile-full' || e.target !== '.preview--more' ) {
       console.log( 'preview--more click--' + (e.target == '.preview--more'))
       console.log(e.target)
       $('.profile-full').removeClass('profile-full__active')
    }
});
```

```css
.profile-full {display: none;}
.profile-full__active {display: block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="profile-full profile-full__active">
   <p>text</p>
</div>

<button class="preview--more">
  click
</button>
```

Что мне надо: Если клик не на `.profile-full` или `.preview--more`, тогда скрываем блок `.profile-full`, иначе - условие не сработает.

Что я вижу в браузере: первый лог говорит о том, что клик по `preview--more` выдает `false`, а второй лог показывает, что клик был по `preview--more`.

Почему так происходит?

Ну и клик по `preview--more` скрывает нужный мне блок, хотя не должен, ведь клик как раз таки по `preview--more`

Comment: Что такое `e`? Если это объект события, то `e.target` никогда не будет строкой и естественно сравнение строки и не-строки даст `false`. Приведите [mcve] без всяких там «в консоли это», потому что иначе нам придётся гадать на кофейной гуще

Comment: @andreymal добавил в тему

Answer (score 2):

Ошибочное условие: `e.target` - это **html элемент**

Однако сравнивается он со строкой и, так как используется `==`, в процессе сравнения операнды  в данном случае будут приведены к строке.

После приведения строка из `e.target` не будет равна ни `.profile-full`, ни `.preview--more` поэтому условие будет выполняться *всегда*.

Кроме того, в условии присутствует логическая ошибка:

> первый лог говорит о том, что клик по preview--more выдает false, а второй лог показывает, что клик был по preview--more.

Само условие построено так, что результат вполне корректный, так как если бы `e.target` был бы равен `.preview--more`, то сработало бы условие `e.target !== '.profile-full'` и управление переходит внутрь `if`.

Вместо сравнения со строкой стоит проверять наличие указанного класса, например с помощью метода [`.classList.contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

```
if(e.target.classList.contains('profile-full') || e.target.classList.contains('preview--more'))
```

Comment: @Darth, как-то странно сниппет добавил, надо было тогда внутрь тоже логи хотя б добавить

Answer (score 0):

Решение таково:

```
    if($(e.target).attr('class') !== 'preview--more' ) {
        if($(e.target).parents('.profile-full').length == 0) {
            $('.profile-full').removeClass('profile-full__active')
        }
    }
```

Спасибо Darth за наводку